# OpenCart adding page to the layout

Tags: php, opencart

In every module and section of opencart we see a drop down called layout. Which usually contains pages such as category, news, product, default, home, etc...

How can I add a page to this section?

Now, I can  add a CONTENT_PAGE via information->insert.

Else, I usually do it by creating a controller and a template, but the page I create is not formally recognized by opencard.

My question is that I should I make open card recognize my page which I create by making a controller and a template manually within the project folder. How?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Though these questions suit more for OpenCart forum instead of SO, I'll try to answer the first one shortly:

**How can I add a page to this section?**
Go to administration -> System -> Desgin -> Layouts and click on **Insert** button. Here You can define a new layout (e.g. You have a custom page with controller that is accessed via URL `index.php?route=information/mycustominformation`, add it's route `information/mycustominformation` as a new layout route).

The second problem is completely unclear to me. Can You be more specific and describe in more details?