# Getting Opencart custom page show for modules

Tags: php

I just created a custom page called store in opencart. For that, I created three files in opencart directory. ..\template\common\store.tpl, ..language\english\common\store.php and ..\catalog\controller\common\store.php. After adding these files, http://localhost/store/index.php?route=common/store shows me the home page with headers and footers.

The question is I am not able to add modules into the page as it is not displayed in "Layout" drop down under modules. For example, If I go to  extensions and "Account", I am not able to find this page under layout dropdown so that I can add account module.

Can someone please help?

Thanks,
Praveen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for adding page to layout in open cart Go to administration -> System -> Design -> Layouts and click on Insert button. Here You can define a new layout (e.g. You have a custom page with controller that is accessed via URL index.php?route=information/mycustominformation, add it's route information/mycustominformation as a new layout route).

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems like someone had already answered the same question in :
[OpenCart adding page to the layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23736415/opencart-adding-page-to-the-layout?rq=1)

Thanks for the answer in that post. This is my first post and I cannot upvote the person yet.